# Incorrect syntax near 'AUTO_INCREMENT'

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I get an error on AUTO_INCREMENT while creating the following table. Please help.

```
CREATE TABLE Invoice( 
Invoice_No INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
Order_ID INT NOT NULL, 
TotalPrice VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
Quantity VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (Invoice No), 
FOREIGN KEY (Order_ID) REFERENCES OrderInfo (Order_ID) );
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you're using MySQL, since AUTO_INCREMENT doesn't work for other DBs such as SQL Server (use `Identity(1, 1)` instead with it).
2. Use `Invoice_No` and not `Invoice No` when marking it as the PK.